# Error connecting Module to Edge Hub using Node sdk- NotConnectedError: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: node.js, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Edge Module node client is unable to connect to Edge Hub over MQTT. It throws a cert error - `NotConnectedError: unable to get local issuer certificate`.

Cert is set an option for the client,

```
var certFile = process.env.EdgeModuleCACertificateFile;
var connectionString = process.env.EdgeHubConnectionString
var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Protocol);

var options = {
    ca: fs.readFileSync(certFile,'utf-8').toString(),
};
client.setOptions(options,()=>{
    console.log('Client transport option set');
});
client.open(connectCallback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help without knowing some details about your environment:
Are you running inside a docker container?
What base image did you use?
How are you starting the container -- are you launching it manually or letting the EdgeAgent launch it for you?

A few things that you can try:

1) Verify that you're using @modules-preview code.  NPM makes this easy to get wrong.

```
PS F:\temp> npm list | findstr "azure-iot"
+-- azure-iot-device-mqtt@1.4.0-modules-preview
| +-- azure-iot-common@1.5.0-modules-preview
| +-- azure-iot-device@1.4.0-modules-preview
| | +-- azure-iot-http-base@1.3.3-modules-preview
| +-- azure-iot-mqtt-base@1.3.3-modules-preview
```

2) Verify that your connection string is well formed.  It needs to have  moduleId= and gatewayHostName= values.  The gatewayHostName should be referencing your edgeHub host.

3) Verify the cert file referenced in EdgeModuleCACertificateFile exists and looks like a valid PEM file (e.g. text file wrapped in -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/-----END CERTIFICATE---- with a bunch of lines of encoded text in between).

Comment: It is running inside a Docker container.
Base image node:8.11.1-alpine.
EdgeAgent is launching the container.

Solution 1 solved the issue. Thanks